# Higher Observational Type Theory: variables becoming free in reduction rules

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, normalization, free-variables

This question is based on  the talks given by Mike Shulman on higher observational type theory ([part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrxkVzItMzA), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ciDNfmvMdU), [part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pDddxB7LbE)).

In trying to understand the reduction rules of the calculus, I tried to work through some examples using the rules present on slide 7 in part 2 (I've copied in a screenshot below, and am assuming there's a missing $\Delta$ on the LHS for the dependent product/function case, but I could be wrong):

[image: reduction rules]

The below example gave me some trouble, however: It seems that the variable $x$ can 'escape' it's scope:

\begin{aligned}
&Id_{Δ.((Π (x : A) (y : B\:x). C))}^δ(f, g)\\
≡ &\Pi (u, v : A). \Pi(p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)).\: (Id_{(Δ, x:A).(Π (y : B\:x). C)}^{δ, p}  (f\: u, g\: v))\\
≡ &\Pi (u, v : A) (p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)) (m, n : B\: x) (q : Id_{(Δ, x:A).B}^{δ,p}(m, n)). Id_{(Δ, x:A, y:B).C}^{δ, p, q} (f\: u\: m, g\: v\: n)
\end{aligned}

My question basically boils down to: what went wrong here? Am I misinterpreting the rules? Is there a typo on the slides?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I suspect the rules should actually use something like $u : A[δ_l]$, where $δ_l$ is obtained from $δ$ by always choosing the left end point of the identities. Similarly $v$ would use a $δ_r$. I.E. an identity of functions actually turns into a function taking values from each endpoint, which only degenerates to $A$ (no substitutions) for both when it is not dependent on anything in the context.

Comment: Happy to see someone else made the same diagnosis as me!

Comment: I think you can look at the agda development for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess the issue comes from the $\Delta$ you assumed was missing. As far as I can tell, when living over a general telescope, already
$$
Id_{Δ.(Π (x : A) B)}^δ(f, g)
≡ \Pi (u, v : A). \Pi(p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)).(Id_{(Δ, x:A).B}^{δ, p}  (f\: u, g\: v))
$$
is problematic. Indeed, the binder $(u,v : A)$ is not sensible, as $A$ lives over $\Delta$. Rather, you should have something like
$$
Id_{Δ.(Π (x : A) B)}^δ(f, g)
≡ \Pi (u : A[δ_{L}]) (v : A[δ_{R}]). \Pi(p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)).(Id_{(Δ, x:A).B}^{δ, p}  (f\: u, g\: v))
$$
where $δ_{L} : \Delta$ is the list of left endpoints of the telescope of equalities $δ$, and similarly for $δ_{R}$.

If you repeat this, you'll get
\begin{aligned}
&Id_{Δ.((Π (x : A) (y : B\:x). C))}^δ(f, g)\\
≡ &\Pi (u : A[δ_{L}]) (v : A[δ_{R}]) (p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)).\: (Id_{(Δ, x:A).(Π (y : B\:x). C)}^{δ, p}  (f\: u, g\: v))\\
≡ &\Pi (u : A[δ_{L}]) (v : A[δ_{R}]) (p: Id_{Δ.A}^δ (u, v)) (m : B[δ_{L},u]) (n : B[δ_{R},v]) (q : Id_{(Δ, x:A).B}^{δ,p}(m, n)). Id_{(Δ, x:A, y:B).C}^{δ, p, q} (f\: u\: m, g\: v\: n)
\end{aligned}
(using that $(δ,p)_{L}$ is $(δ_{L},u)$ since $u$ is the left endpoint of $p$, and scoping is fine.